# Write custom tag to implement a "dropdown based" date picker

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tags, datepicker

I would like to write a custom tag for a date picker containing 3 dropdowns (day, month and year). The dynamic parameters for this date picker would only be the "name" and the number of years to display back from current year. When using this tag in my JSP it would be something like:

```
<library:dropdownDatePicker name="example" yearsBack="10"/>
```

I know how to extend BodyTagSupport class and write the HTML content for this by writing 3 `<form:select />` elements and populating them with options. What I don't know is how to bind the selected day, month and year to a single Date field. I know how to do that in my Java application but not in the custom tag definition.

Ideally, I would like to bind this date field with Spring to a date field of a Bean in my form:

```
<form:form commandName="formBean">
    <library:dropdownDatePicker name="example" yearsBack="10" path="someDateFieldInFormBean"/>
</form:form>
```

I hope this explanation is clear. Could someone help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In dropdownDatePicker you have ${path} (which is "someDateFieldInFormBean" in your example).
Extend it's type with year, month and day fields with accessors and mutators, then in the dropdownDatePicker-tag, set the field's path to ${path}.year, ${path}.month and ${path}.day

eg:
Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = BASE_URL + "/test", produces = TEXT_HTML) public String test(final Model uiModel) {

    Formstuff formstuff = new Formstuff();
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.setYear(1234L);
    datePicker.setMonth(2345L);
    datePicker.setDay(3456L);
    formstuff.setDatePicker(datePicker);

    uiModel.addAttribute("formstuff", formstuff);

    return "test";
}
```

Formstuff class:

```
class Formstuff {
    private DatePicker datePicker;

    public DatePicker getDatePicker() {
        return datePicker;
    }

    public void setDatePicker(final DatePicker datePicker) {
        this.datePicker = datePicker;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Formstuff [datePicker=" + datePicker + "]";
    }

}
```

Datepicker class:

```
public class DatePicker {
    private Long year;
    private Long month;
    private Long day;

    public Long getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(final Long year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Long getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(final Long month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public Long getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(final Long day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DatePicker [year=" + year + ", month=" + month + ", day=" + day + "]";
    }
}
```

Related jsp:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" version="2.0">

    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <util:pageBody title="Datepicker test page" >
        <form:form commandName="formstuff">
            <util:datepicker name="example" yearsBack="10" path="datePicker"/>
        </form:form>
    </util:pageBody>
</jsp:root>
```

And the tag:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
      xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
      xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"  version="2.0">

  <jsp:directive.attribute name="name" type="java.lang.String"
        description="" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="path" type="java.lang.String"
        description="" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="yearsBack" type="java.lang.Long"
        description="" />

  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <h1>${name}</h1>
  <h1>${path}</h1>
  <h1>${yearsBack}</h1>

  <form:input path="${path}.year" />
  <form:input path="${path}.month" />
  <form:input path="${path}.day" />
  <input type="submit"/>

</jsp:root>
```

I hope, my answer was helpful.